# Space around the outside of div

Tags: html, css

Firstly, i'm new to both HTML and css, so don't be too hash. I have a large header div that I wish to place it flush at the top of the screen, however, there appears to be space of about 10px which I can't remove.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{width:300px; background-color: red; height: 300px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Show us more code, it's very hard to figure out what's going on from such a small snippet.

Comment: If you are in chrome or mozilla you can right click an element and go "Inspect element", from there you could try to find the element that has this margin/padding that is bothering you.

Comment: Use a CSS reset, to clear the default body margin/padding settings: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to CSS and stuff,

you need to know that the browser applies styles to elements by default.
Like for example to *Headings* the font-size and font-weight,
to context elements like `i`, `b`, `span` other properties like `display` `inline`,
and to DIV elements the `display:block;` etc...

**if you take a look at [THIS LIST](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)** you'll see that `8px` are added to the `body` element.

If you're happy with the styles the browser adds by default to your elements than all you need is

```
body{
   margin:0; /* to remove the 8px default */
}
```

otherwise if you're not happy at all, and you wish to have full control over the styles being applied to your elements you can use an *Ugly Reset* (for margin and padding urgency) using the *Universal Selector* `*`

```
*{ margin:0; padding:0; } /* Global reset. "*" is to target all elements. */
```

**or Google for some *Stylesheet Reset*** code like from: http://www.cssreset.com/
that will help you to control/reset the most of all other elements default styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that to the body as well.  The DIV is inside the BODY.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

To the body and the html elements